# Macro that interchanges 2 arguments

Tags: c, macros

> Define a macro `swap(t, x, y)` that interchanges two arguments of type `t`.(Block structure will help.)

The ideea is that a variable defined in a block structure exists only inside the block structure. So, I can create a temporary variable without affecting the code.

Here is my solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define swap(t, x, y) {t tmp = x; x = y; y = tmp;}

int main() {
    int x = 10, y = 2;
    swap(int, x, y);

    printf("%d %d", x, y);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I see that you have made a recent edit that invalidates some advice in the answers.  It is often not recommended to make changes to your code once it has been reviewed (or even posted).  Therefore, I have rolled back your edit so that all the answers can still be considered valid.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are using GCC, we can use the [`typeof()`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Typeof.html)<sup>(C99)</sup> keyword to get rid of one of the arguments.  Also, [add a `do-while` so the macro to be used in contexts where it would otherwise be problematic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/154136/1937270).

```
#define SWAP(a, b) do { typeof(a) t; t = a; a = b; b = t; } while(0)
```

---

You could also use an exclusive-or (`^=`) to get rid of that temporary variable, but that only works for integers.

```
#define SWAP(a, b) do { a ^= b; b ^= a; a ^= b; } while(0)
```

Comment: But that doesn't support other arguments than ints (or other ordinal types), does it?

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg You are correct.  I have added in another solution that works with more types than just `int`s.

Comment: Note that is you are using GCC 4.9, a somewhat better solution would be to use the `__auto_type` extension whose behaviour is similar to the C++11 keyword `auto`.

Answer (score 10):

First, macros should have `ALL_CAPS` names to distinguish them from functions.  Users need to be able to distinguish macros from functions because they behave slightly differently.  For example, with your definition of `swap()` as a macro, this code (for illustration purposes — not that it's good code) fails to compile:

```
if (swap(int, x, y), x) {
    /* Do something */
}
```

Also, I'd put a [defensive `do { ... } while (0)`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/154136/1157100) around your definition.  Otherwise, this would cause an unexpected compilation error:

```
int main() {
    int x = 10, y = 0;
    if (x != 0)
        SWAP(int, x, y);
    else
        x = 0;
    printf("%d %d\n", x, y);
    return 0;
}
```